# Get list of opened popup windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if I can get a list of popups opened by window.open javascript function call.

I want to run some code after all these pages are closed. I don't mind if the solution was plain javascript or JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't get a list of windows opened by the page via `window.open` (sadly). You'll have to keep track of them as you open them (assuming it's you who opens them).

If you were to do the more modern style of popup instead (positioned elements opened as virtual windows within the page), then of course you could readily get a list of them by doing a simple selector query (just add a class to them when they're showing, and then query the DOM for elements with that class).

Comment: I just wanna add this answer because this is an alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340160/how-to-get-the-references-of-all-already-opened-child-windows

Answer (score -3):

you can use localstorage to do this. I am also using a localstorage plugin so the set and get are short hand.

```
function Op(r,rr,rrr){
    if(!rrr){rrr={};};if(!rrr.n){rrr.n='PopUps'}
    ii={o:jQuery.localStorage.get(rrr.n)}
    if(!ii.o){
        switch(rrr.n){
            case'unmOptions':
                ii.o={audio0:1,audio1:1}
            break;
            default:
                ii.o={p:{}}
            break;
        }
    }
    if(r&&rr&&!rrr.x){
        ii.o[r]=rr;
    }
    switch(rrr.x){
        case 0:
            delete(ii.o[r])
        break;
        case 1:
            delete(ii.o[r][rr])
        break;
    }
    jQuery.localStorage.set(rrr.n,ii.o)
    return ii.o
}
```

How to get object of windows

```
Op()
Op().p['window1']
```

to set values

```
Op('key','value')
```

to delete values

```
Op('key','',{x:0})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and example code but could you please edit your code in future examples to make it easier to follow, its hard to keep track with the variable/handle names your using, r, rr, rrr, ii,r, ii,io, iii,r and so on, its pretty confusing to follow.   Perhaps use English words in your variable names that reflect what they are.