# stripe checkout, custom integration: how to detect abort?

Tags: javascript, callback, stripe-payments

A followup to @mjmarsh's [stripe question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441814/stripe-simple-checkout-detect-if-close-button-is-clicked):

How can I detect if **the stripe checkout payment process was aborted by the user** (close button was clicked in the checkout widget)?

@mjmarsh telling screenshot:
[image]

As commented in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21442440/1598477), the `close` callback is called no matter whether it was cancelled or successful.

There is the `token` callback, but I don't know how that info could be perused inside the `close` function, and how reliable that would be.

Comment: There is no guaranteed order as far as I know and it seems to depend on browsers. What I usually do is add a setTimeout in the `close` callback and if `token` hasn't fired after a second I assume it was closed by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's to do, in pseudocode

1. I declare a `ok = false` variable in the appropriate scope.
2. I set it to true first thing inside the `token` callback.
3. I check for the `ok` variable inside the `close` callback.

And here's some real code to copy and paste:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_xxxxxxx',
        isTokenGenerate: false,
        token: function (token) {
            handler.isTokenGenerate = true;

            //Add the stuff if required
        }
    });

    window.addEvent('domready', function () { 

        handler.open({
            name: 'Add Name',
            description: 'Add Description',
            amount: '1000',
            currency: 'USD',
            opened: function () {

            },
            closed: function () {
                if (!handler.isTokenGenerate) {

                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here's what I do at the moment:

1. I declare a `ok = false` variable in the appropriate scope.
2. I set it to true first thing inside the `token` callback.
3. I check for the `ok` variable inside the `close` callback.

It seems to work - but I don't know if it will always work. It would be useful to get stripe to tell us if the one callback is *always* called *after* the other.