# In html is there a way to get a list of all popup documents?

Tags: javascript, popup

In html5, is there a function like:

```
document.getAllPopups()
```

which returns all popup windows that the current window has opened. For example if I did

```
var P = window.open("blah.com");
```

then `P == document.getAllPopups()[0]` should be `true`.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: No there is not. Store a reference to the window when you create it. Put it in an array and loop over it.

Comment: this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340160/how-to-get-the-references-of-all-already-opened-child-windows