# npm library UNIX time to D-M-Y

Tags: javascript, unix, npm

Is there an npm library for conversion from unix time to day month year? Or, ideally just the time and day and month? I can't really find an easy to use library that I can just port in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate timestamp unix epoch format nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250551/how-to-generate-timestamp-unix-epoch-format-nodejs)

Comment: No, I am taking a unix time and converting it to a usable calendar date, particularly time. I am not using the date library of javascript to convert to UNIX time as the question you submitted proposes. The titles are confusingly similar.

Comment: npm library is same as javascript. i dont see any differenece.

Comment: UNIX time => D-M-Y, not D-M-Y => UNIX time.

Comment: if u looking for native solution, Please check my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is the JavaScript library for all your date and time manipulation needs.

```
moment.unix(unixTimestampInSeconds).format('D-M-Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) should fulfill your requirements

Answer (score 0):

> Without third-party lib, simple implement.

```js
let unixTime = 1585737917;
function padStart(num, d) {
  d = String(d);
  const delta = num - d.length;
  if (delta > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < delta; i++) {
      d = "0" + d;
    }
  }
  return d;
}
const pad = padStart.bind(null, 2);
function parseUnixDate() {
  const date = new Date(unixTime * 1000);
  const [dd, mm, yy] = [
    date.getDate(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    date.getFullYear()
  ];
  return `${pad(dd)}-${pad(mm)}-${yy}`;
}

console.log(parseUnixDate(unixTime));
```