# How to re-evaluate a script that doesn't expose any global in a declarative-style component

Tags: javascript, html, declarative

I have been writing a reusable script, let's call it a plugin although it's **not** jQuery, that can be initialised in a declarative way from the HTML. I have extremely simplified it to explain my question so let's say that if a user inserts a tag like:

```
<span data-color="green"></span>
```

the script will fire because the attribute `data-color` is found, changing the color accordingly.

This approach proved very handy because it avoids anyone using the plugin having to initialise it imperatively in their own scripts with something like:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
myPlugin.init(elem);
```

Moreover by going the declarative way I could get away without defining any global (in this case `myPlugin`), which seemed to be a nice side effect.
I simplified this situation in an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/3sok08Lo/1/), and as you can see a user can avoid writing any js, leaving the configuration to the HTML.

### Current situation

The plugin is wrapped in a closure like so:

```js
;(function(){

  var changeColor = {
    init : function(elem){
       var bg = elem.getAttribute('data-color');            
       elem.style.background = bg;
    }
  };

  // the plugin itslef looks for appropriate HTML elements 
  var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]')[0];

  // it inits itself as soon as it is evaluated at page load
  changeColor.init(elem);

})();
```

The page loads and the span gets the correct colour, so everything is fine.

### The problem

What has come up lately, though, is the need to let the user re-evaluate/re-init the plugin when he needs to.
Let's say that in the first example the HTML is changed dynamically **after** the page is loaded, becoming:

```
<span data-color="purple"></span>
```

With the first fiddle there's no way to re-init the plugin, so I am now testing some solutions.

### Possible solutions

#### Exposing a global

The most obvious is exposing a global. If we go this route the fiddle becomes

http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/089om9z5/4/

where the only real difference is removing the selection of the element, leaving it to the user:

```js
// we remove this line
// var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]')[0];
```

and adding something like (again, i am simplifying for the sake of the question):

```js
 window.changeColor = changeColor;
```

to the above code in order to expose the `init` method to be called from anywhere.
Although this works I am not satisfied with it. I am really looking for an alternative solution, as I don't want to lose the ease of use of the original approach and I don't want to force anyone using the script adding a new global to their projects.

#### Events

One solution I have found is leveraging events. By putting something like this in the plugin body:

```js
elem.addEventListener('init', function() {
  changeColor.init(elem);
}, false);
```

anybody will be able to just create an event an fire it accordingly. An example in this case:

```js
var event = new CustomEvent('init', {});
span.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This would re-init the plugin whenever needed. A working fiddle is to be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/tgztjdzL/1/

### The question (finally)

My question is: is there a cleaner/better way of handling this? 
How can i let people using this plugin without the need of a global or having to initialise the script themselves the first time? Is event the best way or am I missing some more obvious/better solutions?

Comment: You will want to have a look at [Web Components](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) and [Mutation Observers](http://addyosmani.com/blog/mutation-observers/)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I know both of them, but in this case I am happy with letting the user decide when to update the dom so I think that a very simple solution can be found without using Mutation observers or listening to any particular change on DOM level.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Element.setAttribute` to trigger your plugin:

```
var oldSetAttribute = Element.prototype.setAttribute;
Element.prototype.setAttribute = function(name, value) {
  oldSetAttribute.call(this, name, value);
  if (name === 'data-color') {
    changeColor.init(this);
  }
}
```

Pros:

- User does not have to explicitly re-initialize the plugin.  It will happen automatically when required.

Cons:

- This will, of course, only work if the user changes `data-color` attributes using `setAttribute`, and not if they create new DOM elements using `innerHTML` or via some other approach.
- Modifying host object prototypes is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes) [by many](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea), and for good reasons.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: I would guess that *most* of the typical DOM manipulations do not use `setAttribute`…