# What's the substitute for jQuery's each() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery we have a function each like this

```
$('button').each(function(i) {
  $('button').eq(i).css('background', 'red');
});
```

How can we replace this code with plain JavaScript?

Comment: Well there's `Array.prototype.forEach()`, but by itself it can't replace *that* code.

Comment: Just use a `for…of` loop.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***DOM selection with `querySelectorAll()`***

Browsers have several ways to select elements from the DOM, but perhaps the most flexible and convenient is `querySelectorAll`. It lets you use CSS style selectors to grab all matching elements from a given root.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button");
```

---

***Shortening `querySelectorAll()`***

As nice as that is, it is a little verbose, so it's not uncommon to create a wrapping function that shortens it. That's what we'll do here, giving it the name `Q`.

```
function Q(root, selector) {
  if (typeof root === "string") {
    selector = root
    root = document
  }
  return root.querySelectorAll(selector)
}
```

The first argument is the context from which you're doing the selection, and the second is the selector. If you only pass a string, it'll use `document` as the context.

So now your DOM selection would be this, which we'll use hereafter:

```
Q("button");
```

---

***Borrowing `Array.prototype.forEach`***

A pretty common way to do a functional looping construct is to borrow the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method of `Array.prototype` and call it on the collection of elements by using the function's [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(Q("buttons"), function(el) {
  el.style.background = "red";
});
```

Or in the most modern browsers, we can use arrow functions to shorten it a little:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(Q("buttons"), el => el.style.background = "red");
```

---

***Binding and caching the borrowed `.forEach()`***

The `.forEach()` borrow can be shortened if early in your application, you use the Function prototype's [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to bind the `.forEach()` method to the `this` value of `.call()`.

```
const each = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);
```

That way you can just call it like a function that receives the element collection as the first argument.

```
each(Q("button"), function(el) {
  el.style.background = "red";
});
```

Or again using an arrow function in some of the newest browsers:

```
each(Q("button"), el => el.style.background = "red");
```

---

***Using `Array.from()`***

The [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method was also introduced to easily convert array-like objects into actual arrays. This would let you use `.forEach()` directly, and can be patched into legacy browsers with a simple polyfill *(see the docs link)*.

```
Array.from(Q("button")).forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.background = "red";
});
```

If you put the `Array.from` call directly in our `Q` function from above, you'll be able to call `.forEach()` directly.

```
Q("button").forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.background = "red";
});
```

---

***Using a `for-of` loop***

In the latest browsers, you can use a [`for-of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead, making everything very short and clean:

```
for (const el of Q("button")) {
  el.style.background = "red";
}
```

This way there's no need to convert to an `Array` or use `.forEach`.

---

***Transpiling modern code***

For the examples above that require the most modern browsers, there are transpilers available (for example [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) that will translate the latest standards into code that will work in older browsers.

---

***Creating a custom `each()`***

As a side note, if you'd like `this` to refer to the current element, or have any other specific behavior, here's a basic `each` implementation that receives the collection and a callback.

```
function each(a, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    callback.call(a[i], a[i], i, a);
  }
}
```

Though using `this` in that way is generally not needed since you already have the element as a parameter.

Comment: Nice. But in jQuery's `$(...).each()`, `this` would point to the element.

Comment: @haim770:  That's true, though I think the OP simply wanted to know how to do that kind of loop in JS, and not necessarily have it exactly as it would behave in jQuery.

Comment: @squint Why did you make this a CW?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: All my answers are that way (or I change them as I come across non-CW ones). I want others to feel comfortable adding information and improvements to the answers I post.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `getElementsByTagName()` which queries the DOM for elements of a certain tag and returns a collection of elements.  You can call this function on `document` or you could be more specific and select an element using `document.getElementById()` and then look for tags inside of that element.

Either way, once you have a collection of elements, you can then loop over the collection and apply styles accordingly.

```
//query the document for all <button> elements
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

/* -- OR -- */

//query the document for all buttons inside of a specific element
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var buttons = container.getElementsByTagName('button');

//loop over the collection of buttons and set each background to 'red'
for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.background = "red";
}
```

Edit: I realize this is not the JS behind how jQuery's each function works. OP didn't state that he wanted to see that specifically, just a way to accomplish the `$.each()` functionality with JS (as there are many possibilities). This example is just a trivial approach using a very basic concept.

Answer (score 4):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for(var x in buttons){
  var e = buttons[x];
  e.innerHTML="stuff";
}
```

as squint pointed out, it should be buttons[x] and var x.
sorry about that.

Comment: oops forgot about the e=buttons[x]

Answer (score 3):

Supported by more browsers since it doesn't use `forEach`.

If using `getElementsByTagName`, add the function to [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.each = function(callback){
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++) callback(this[i]);
};

document.getElementsByTagName('div').each(function(div){
    div.innerHTML = "poo";
});
```

If using `querySelectorAll` you can attach the same function to [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

```
NodeList.prototype.each = function(callback){
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++) callback(this[i]);
};

document.querySelectorAll('div').each(function(div){
    div.innerHTML = "podo";
});
```

To appease the chanters (see comments), I'll specify that if this is for a library you're writing, or if it will be used alongside a library that could possibly overwrite it, obviously you would want to consider other methods.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er5amk8j/

Comment: [Don't modify objects you don't own.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6223449/3853934)

Comment: @Gothdo Don't make blanket statements that only apply in certain contexts and otherwise make no sense at all.

Comment: If you don't think that applies in your context, please explain that.

Comment: i said what i intended to say. it's the same mantra people are always chanting about `eval`. if the functionality didn't have any value or purpose it wouldn't be part of the standard. you (and everyone chanting with you) are doing more harm than good by making blanket statements about what functionality to use and what not to. you're the one making the claim so the burden of explanation is on you..

Comment: The explanation is in the question I linked: "The problem is that prototype can be modified in several places. For example one library will add map method to Array's prototype and your own code will add the same but with another purpose. So one implementation will be broken."

Comment: your original statement was "don't do so and so" it didn't have any exceptions or conditions. without coditions, your statement is inaccurate and unhelpful, and with the appropriate conditions it's barely relevant.

Answer (score 2):

But you are also using `$.each()` in a dubious way in your example. It is much easier and faster to access elements using `this`.

```
$('button').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

Most simple replacement would be using simple function closures but it's not pretty.

```
var $buttons = $('button');

for(var i = 0; i < $buttons.length; i++){
  (function(i){
    $buttons.eq(i).css('background', 'red');
  })(i);
}
```

Or to set `this` use `.call()` to invoke function.

```
var $buttons = $('button');

for(var i = 0; i < $buttons.length; i++){
  (function(i){
    $(this).css('background', 'red');    
  }).call($buttons[i], i);
}
```

Comment: The IIFE wouldn't actually be needed in the second example because `i` is used immediately in the loop instead of later in a callback. You're right about the OP's technique though. Calling `$('button')` over and over in the loop will be slow.

Comment: @squint You are right. But I've expanded `Michael Hamilton` answer on purpose to show that although results are same it is not proper way to replace `.each()`.