# How can I make an extension method on `any` type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to make an extension method so I can easily print out any typescript primitive or object in human-readable form.  So instead of doing `JSON.stringify(thing)` I can do `thing.printNice()`

Is this possible?  I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
interface any {
    printNice(): string
}

any.prototype.printNice = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this)
}
```

Edit: I see now that this has been asked and the answer is no, you can't. 
 Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  Typing `JSON.stringify(thing)` all over the place is annoying.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. any, boolean, number... are not objects, they are types. Types do not have a prototype attribute. I think there's no hack to build an extension method in this case.

Comment: `any` is a _type_: there's no such `any.prototype` object to add a method to. I see you want it to be like Go's Receiver functions or something, but that's not a thing in TypeScript.

Comment: "so I can easily print out any typescript primitive or object in human-readable form" --- you don't need a method for that, just a function is enough.

Comment: Also, with respect, the assertion "Typing JSON.stringify(thing) all over the place is annoying" is a problem of _your IDE_: get one autocompletes with intellisense rather than polluting global Object prototypes.

Comment: @msanford I'm using VS code.  What usually happens is I print a bunch of variables with `console.log` and forget to stringify it, then go back and wrap the variables in `JSON.stringify`.  You're right, a better solution would be to be have a macro or something where I can highlight it and auto stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible* - nearly everything inherits from `Object.prototype`, so you can put the method on `Object.prototype`:

```js
Object.prototype.printNice = function() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
};

(5).printNice();
({ foo: 'bar' }).printNice();
```

In Typescript syntax:

```
declare global {
    interface Object {
        printNice: () => void;
    }
}
Object.prototype.printNice = function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
};

(5).printNice();
({ foo: 'bar' }).printNice();
```

But this is probably not a good idea, because objects do not expect to have a `printNice` property. Mutating the built-in objects [can easily create problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes).

Note that objects which do *not* inherit from `Object.prototype` won't have the method in their prototype chain:

```js
Object.prototype.printNice = function() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
};

const someObj = Object.create(null);
someObj.foo = 'bar';
// Error, property does not exist:
someObj.printNice();
```

(but almost all objects, including primitive wrappers, do inherit from `Object.prototype`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't. `any` is not a class or an interface. It's a construct (type technically) for lack of other words. same as `var` (as a type not the keyword) or an anonymous object. it's what you want it to be, so it cannot be extended

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Object`  instead.

```
Object.prototype.printNice = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this)
}
```

And then:

```
function myFunc() {
  return 42;
}
console.log(myFunc.printNice());
```