# using $ instead of querySelector()

Tags: javascript

I want to implement something to make myself instead of writing something.querySelector() to write $, I've fixed the half of the problem which is when I want to make `document.querySelector()` instead, I can now use  `$`

```
<div>
<button>hi</button>
</div>
    let $ = (x) => {
        return document.querySelector(x);
    }
div = $("div");
```

But the thing that I want to do now is to select the button from inside the div, so now I can't do:

```
div.$("button");
```

I want to do it, I know a little bit about prototypes, but I don't know how to implement this thing, How?

[EDIT]: I've seen many people saying that It's a bad implementation, could you please tell why?

Comment: try using children like `div.children()`

Comment: If you want to use it like that, you would probably have to attach `$` to the `Element.prototype`

Comment: @Taplar, good answer, I was reading about that on MDN a few seconds ago, when I do that, do I need to keep the function I've written? in other words, will this solution replace the need for the function I've written (for the " document. " )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with prototypes, you can have `$` accept a second argument, the parent to select from.

```js
const $ = (x, parent = document) => {
  return parent.querySelector(x);
}
const div = $("div");
const button = $('button', div);
console.log(button);
```

```html
<div>
  <button>hi</button>
</div>
```

Changing prototypes is bad practice, but it's doable:

```js
const $ = (x, parent = document) => {
  return parent.querySelector(x);
}
Element.prototype.$ = function(selector) {
  return $(selector, this);
}
const div = $("div");
const button = div.$('button');
console.log(button);
```

```html
<div>
  <button>hi</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very good idea, but Huh, I want to miss with prototypes, I love the hard things

Comment: Could you please tell why it's a bad idea to implement that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes offers a few explanations

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.$ = HTMLElement.prototype.$ = function(selector) {
  if (this === window) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  } else {
    return this.querySelector(selector);
  }
};

console.log($('div').$('button'));
```

```html
<div>
<button>hi</button>
</div>
```

You can, I don't know if I would, put the method on the window and HTMLElement prototype to allow chaining like you asked about.

Comment: Don't think adding the function to `window` object is necessary. You could define the function separately and then add it to `HTMLElement` prototype --> `HTMLElement.prototype.$ = $;`. This way you can call it as function or as a method on an html element.

Comment: I just chained it like this, because `var $ = method` in the global scope is essentially just attaching it to the window anyway. @Yousaf  And if you look at the snippet, I *am* calling it as a function and a method, :)

Comment: Personally I would argue that this whole approach is problematic.  For those familiar with jQuery, the gut reaction to seeing `$` being used is to expect that it is jQuery.  Using it like this is bound to lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended, but you can modify `Element.prototype` and `Document.prototype`.

```
Element.prototype.$ = Document.prototype.$ = function(x){
    return this.querySelector(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best approach but you could assign a property $ to the element that is a function that queries that element

```js
let $ = (x) => {
  let el = document.querySelector(x)
  el.$ = (y) => el.querySelector(y)
  return el;
}
div = $("div");

console.log(div.$('button'))
```

```html
<div>
  <button>hi</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's very simple and you need only two lines of code to make it all work as expected.**

```
Document.prototype.$ = Document.prototype.querySelector
Element.prototype.$ = Element.prototype.querySelector
```