# Which JS concept can ensure the code runs?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can someone please help me understand what concept from JavaScript could ensure below line of code runs? feel free to make code changes to make it execute & provide output.

```js
    (20).add(10).multiply(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `prototype`. Using `.prototype`, you are adding a property in the prototype chain to all numbers.

Any number can use it.

```js
Number.prototype.add = function(x){
return this + x;
}
console.log((20).add(10));
Number.prototype.multiply = function(x){
return this * x;
}
console.log((20).multiply(10));

console.log((20).add(10).multiply(2));
```

**Note: This is generally a bad practice, and should only be used for self-learning and practice.**

Comment: While this is accurate and worth knowing about, it's also worth pointing out that modifying common objects prototypes is generally considered bad practise. See: [Why is it frowned upon to modify JavaScript object's prototypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for pointing that out. I have added in the answer in BOLD