# Add typed function to array prototype

Tags: typescript, undefined, prototype

I have a function written in typescript which takes an array of type `(T | undefined)[]` and filters out all undefined values, so that the resulting type is only T.

```js
function filterUndefined<T>(ts: (T | undefined)[]): T[] {
  return ts.filter((t: T | undefined): t is T => t !== undefined);
}
```

This works fine, but i'd like to add that to the array prototype. Is is possible to do that and have the typings correct?

When i try to do it like this:

```js
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    filterUndefined: () => Array<T>
  }
}

Array.prototype.filterUndefined = () => {
  return this.filter(x !== undefined)
};
```

T includes undefined and so i don't have the advantage, that the resulting type has no undefined in it.

Using

```js
interface Array<T | undefined> {
  filterUndefined: () => Array<T>;
}
```

seems to be no valid TS code.

Is it even possible to do what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Exclude<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility in the return type:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        filterUndefined: () => Array<Exclude<T, undefined>>;
    }
}
```

Your implementation should also use `function () {` instead of `() => {` so it can have `this` refer to the array itself (otherwise, it refers to `globalThis`).

```
Array.prototype.filterUndefined = function () {
    return this.filter((x) => x !== undefined);
};
```

Now, it'll filter out `undefined` from the array type:

```
const filtered = ["string", undefined].filterUndefined();
//    ^? string[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoeB8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgIIwxQCeAPACoB8O+h-VIhAowAqiVCCSIYAC54ACgCU8ALw9GzdgFEAHpACuoTgBp4BiSCkyuXANx8CAX1wvcm1gDoADjBRl-Fm8QT0FhSnFJUhk1eCoLMDIiFBJFFTx+ODIDGFSyAAsiAGdQoREFBV0VdXhdeABCVVVzS2tgJQcnB1wwFKKyOLLKGOaAbQAifphSRHGzCyjpYABdUvCxVujgZQcAel3+AD0AflxcEF1vFBgB7C74ffhMVAB3IvN3gI+EUEhYBGQ6EwuCAA)

---

Please see [Why is it frowned upon to modify JavaScript object's prototypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes)

Comment: Thank you, i did not know about the exclude utility. This works fine for me. :)