# Can I create a function in TypeScript that accepts any function and returns a function with the same type signature?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to know if it's possible to create a function in TypeScript that takes any other function as an argument, and returns a new function with a modified type signature that can be called in the same way as the original.

An obvious use case for this would be generic 'catch' and 'finally' modifiers that take in a function and return a new version of it that executes the same but handles any errors that are thrown.

An example:

```js
declare global {
    interface Function {
        catch(catchFn: (error) => void): Function;
    }
}

Function.prototype.catch = function(catchFn) {
    return (...props) => {
        try {
            return this(...props);
        }
        catch(error) {
            catchFn(error);
        }
    }
}

function fn(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    if (!firstName || !lastName) {
        throw new Error('First name and last name are required.');
    }

    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}

const safeFn = fn.catch(console.error);

console.log(safeFn('Dave', undefined)); // Logs 'First name and last name are required' to console.
console.log(safeFn('Dave', 'Dave')); // Logs 'Dave Dave' to the console.
```

The above functions exactly as it should, but because it just returns `Function` all typing information is lost and I can happily call `safeFn` with any arguments I choose, even if the compiler would normally stop me e.g.

```js
fn(Symbol('hello'), 12345, () => console.info('hello')); // It doesn't like this.
safeFn(Symbol('hello'), 12345, () => console.info('hello')); // This is fine.
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to do something like the above while preserving the typing of the original function.

Comment: You could give that a type but it's generally discouraged to start messing with global native JS things like that.  Could you [edit] the example so that you're not doing that?  Say with a standalone `catch()` wrapper function instead?  Otherwise it's very distracting to try to help someone do something that is considered a [Very Bad Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223449/2887218)

Comment: e.g., [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKrY8m) is how I'd do it, but if I wrote that up as an answer it would have **LARGE DISCLAIMERS** on it, and it's just a distraction from your actual question, I think.

Comment: Additionally, this can only really work with `void` returning functions. If you design the function to swallow errors, what's the return-type? `SomeType | void`? You're just making more work for the consumer of your function.

Comment: @jcalz the solution you sent is actually what I wanted. I had pretty much the same code, but had used `[]` instead of `any[]` and so it wasn't working.

Comment: I understand that, but I've asked you to please [edit] the code to avoid modifying global prototypes.  Would you do that, or if not, would you mind if I do it?  Then I'd present [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgBMlW) solution, which has the same effect.  If you want to modify `Function.prototype` in your own code that's fine, but it's best to avoid the topic entirely here.  Let me know how to proceed.