# Safe way to implement Array.bipartition()?

Tags: javascript

While using array I found myself doing `Array.filter(callback)` and `Array.filter(!callback)` toghether quite often so I wanted to call something like **Array.bipartition()**, (which uses a callback to split the array in two partitions based on the evaluation of the callback on the elements of the array)

```js
"use strict";

function bipartition(callback) {
    // this is an array
    return this.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
        if (callback(element)) {
            accumulator[0].push(element);
        } else {
            accumulator[1].push(element);
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, [[], []]);
}

Array.prototype.bipartition = bipartition;

// small test
const isEven = (number) => number % 2 == 0;
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const [even, odd] = array.bipartition(isEven);
console.log(even, odd)
```

This code works but I have read that extending Array.prototype is bad.
Why is it advised against extending the Prototype of Array? How can I do it "safely"?

Comment: [Why is it frowned upon to modify JavaScript object's prototypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223449) - Rather than adding methods to the prototype, create a regular function and pass your array as an argument.

Comment: The safest way would be to either make your own extension of the Array class where you can add to the prototype what you want, or to implement it as a pure function. The reason it's advised against is because the definition of `Array` is determined, so extending it makes it confusing if you ever move to other projects that have not implemented it. Extending the prototype is pretty obtuse, making something like `MyOwnArrayImplementation` is clearly not "part of the core JS" functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it frowned upon to modify JavaScript object's prototypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes)  (link provided above)

Comment: You can also see the impacts that adding methods to the prototype has on development of the JS (ES) spec. For example, more recently, `Array.prototype.group()` had to be changed to `Object.groupBy()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy)). So you may impact a future ES method that's implemented with the same name.