Vue breaks upon Object modification
If I do this:
Object.prototype.breakVue=true;

Vue will break.
How to avoid it?
More details (only if you want more context/details, first section is enough to reproduce the problem):
I wrote an Object plugin which injects many methods I wrote into every object by adding them into Object's prototype.
This works fine with plain JavaScript applications, but if I use Vue, it breaks it.
I use those handy methods in my code.
For example, if I want to make my class final, I do:
export default class FinalClass {}
FinalClass.makeFinal();

which is a handy shortcut for what I would usually have to type:
export default class FinalClass {}
Object.freeze(FinalClass);

and is made possible by injection of the makeFinal method into Object:
Object.prototype.makeFinal=function() { Object.freeze(this); }

I do have my own utility class:
export default class OBJECT { static makeFinal() { Object.freeze(this); } }

which I can use like this:
export default class FinalClass extends OBJECT {}
FinalClass.makeFinal();

but the downside is that all classes in which I want to use this have to extend from OBJECT, plus this does not work for objects which are not created by me. I want to be able to call my method on any object, so I want {}.makeFinal(); to be a valid syntax. Or "text".makeFinal(); and so on. So, I want all built in objects to have my extension methods injected.
Plus it is not just one extension function I wrote for Object. I have tens of them.
This works with plain JavaScript application. But now I want my extensions to be used with Web application which uses Vue. However, this does not work.
I have injected methods into many other JavaScript built in objects, such as Date and Vue worked without problems.
Do you know how to fix Vue? How to allow Vue to work, while allowing, for example, true.and(true); or 5.isGreaterThen(6); or {}.equals({}) to be a valid syntax in my code?

The question lacks clear problem statement. "Vue will break" - in which way? You describe it like a well-known problem, but it's not. Primarily because nobody does this these days, modifying Object.prototype for local needs is a terrible practice that's widely discouraged for various reasons, including possible implications you have with Vue. It's unsafe and it can break things. If you need to access utility function like "makeFinal", just import it. It's ({}).equals({}), not {}.equals({}), etc. In case this was the problem (besides the obvious thing with Object.prototype), then that's it

Well, breaking means that application will not load. Screen will be blank white if I do this. And that is it. Inside the console, Vue gives error Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute and after that execution stops. There are several other errors originating from Vue, but the mentioned one is the last. In my main js file, execution comes to the Vue creation line, and at that line execution is stopped. No further lines are executed.

The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what happens on your side. Which vue version exactly? For the latest vue 3, https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-4jww7c?file=src%2Fmain.js

Oh, sorry, Vue version is 2.5.18. I am sorry, I though this happens in every version with every setup, but it looks like it does not. However, I do not know how to make the application work on the link you provided. If I switch version to 2.5.18 in package.json, it no longer works (even without my line, and if I leave App.vue blank, that is, with blank 
This could be specific to how reactivity is implemented in v2, as it's based on modifying object properties and can be directly affected with Object.prototype in theory. I could see some bugs in v2 with it, but not the error you listed. Any way, if you're unaware yet of the problematics above, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223449 . It was a bad idea even 15-20 y ago based on the experience with Prototype.js lib, and it's an absolute taboo in a modern app that's discouraged by linters and npm audit, this promotes bad design and can affect every script on the page in unpredictable ways.

In case you want it for some reason, the least thing you can do is to make custom properties non-enumerable with defineProperty instead of "=", this at least will prevent other code that uses for..in from breaking, which is known to be sensitive to proto chain. Could be the case with Vue or not

Thank you. Making properties not enumerable solves the problem. I did not think of that. Last time I created non-enumerable properties was in 2019., when I was creating my own JavaScript library, which also modified built-in objects. I did not use it ever since, so I forgot about it.
The problem here was that, at some point, Vue was enumerating all properties, going through each one and was, for some reason, invoking each method. When I put breakpoints in my utility class (where I keep all methods to be injected), I found that each and every method gets invoked by Vue.

This is bad because some methods are pretty bad ones, like the makeFinal method, which invokes freeze upon this. So, it eventually ended up freezing Vue objects and making Vue not able to modify its internal objects. The error I mentioned came from the fact that one of my injected method was named get which is not a good name for a method, so now it is called Get.
Anyway, making injected properties non-enumerable ensures that I can still call them by name, and Vue does not see them, so, everyone is happy.

Thank you. You should have written this as an answer, because now I can not mark this as answered. :)

Yes, as a rule of thumb, any proto keys are non-enumerable, e.g. in native class. it was inconsistent in transpiled code but now this is pretty much standard. Making them unintentionally enumerable is unlikely to help anything but can cause problems. I can see why freeze could  cause problems with Vue 2, its reactivity is pretty hacky too. I'll post an answer, in case this helps someone else
