# How can I use two jQuery Plugins having the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

In a big web project I would like to use a jQuery Plugins `editable` which name is the same of the exiting one but have a different behaviour.
There is a clean way to rename the plugin? Maybe using require.js?

Comment: Edit the source code of one of the plugins.

Comment: you seem to need an additional parameter to the plugin

Comment: GIve us a link to the plugin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740974/jquery-plugins-occupy-the-same-function-name-conflict

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can rename the plugin like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="firstplugin.js"></script>
<script>
    $.fn.editableFirst = $.fn.editable;
</script>
<script src="secondplugin.js"></script>
```

`editableFirst` should be something more meaningful to you.

Comment: Will be possible using require.js to achieve the same result?

Comment: Haven't used it, but some quick research indicates you can supply a callback function to `require` which will be executed after the script(s) is/are loaded.  You can rename the plugin there before loading the second `editable` plugin.